# Jquery find element by id as variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im using jquery to get a list of objects from the server. Every object has two fields `id` and `singleValue` (on the server both of them are Strings). I want to iterate over the list and put values in the correct elements.

```
for(var i=0;i<response.listOfObjects.length;i++){
    $(response.listOfObjects[i].id).val(response.listOfObjects[i].singleValue);
}
```

Nothing happend by running this code. List has correct values (checked it by `alert("id: " + response.listOfObjects[i].id + "  singleValue: " + response.listOfObjects[i].singleValue);`)

I also tried to do

```
$('#' + response.listOfObjects[i].id).val(response.listOfObjects[i].singleValue);
```

but still doesn't work.

How is it possible to solve this problem?

@EDIT
the html looks like:

```
<div class="field-group" style="display: block;" original-title="" title="">
   <label for="customfield_13307">PCN</label>
   <input class="textfield text long-field" id="customfield_13307" name="customfield_13307" maxlength="254" type="text" value="">
   <div class="description">EPCN</div>
</div>
```

The `id` from the object is the id of the input.

@EDIT
I used JSON.stringify(response):

```
    {
   "name":"ATB",
   "listOfObjects":[
      {
         "id":"customfield_13305",
         "type":"single",
         "singleValue":"21766"
      },
      {
         "id":"customfield_13307",
         "type":"Text",
         "singleValue":" aaaa"
      },
      {
         "id":"customfield_13308",
         "type":"Text",
         "singleValue":" bbbb"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Post your sample HTML and sample listOfObjects

Comment: The last example should work. If it doesn't you need to debug the values coming from the object match what's in the DOM, and check there's no errors in the console. With the information you've shown we can't provide any useful help

Comment: `$('#' + response.listOfObjects[i].id)` will work only if your element is input element, what is the type of your HTML element?

Comment: Can you please specify the output which you are trying to achieve? [{id:singleValue}]?

Comment: I saw you edited the HTML, but we also need to see the content of the `response` object to check that the values match up. As I said in my previous comment, the JS code you have works fine (https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/px4qjths/) therefore there either an error in your page or your response is not what you expect.

Comment: Can you post sample response as well?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan let me know if there are all necessary infomrations

Comment: How many elements do you have with id = `#customfield_13305`? You can `console.log( $( "#customfield_13305" ).length );`

Comment: Updated @RoryMcCrossan 's fiddle to show it working fine:  https://jsfiddle.net/m65o24Lq/

Comment: @Eddie there is 1 element with this id

Comment: This code works fine, as you can see in @freedomn-m's fiddle. Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I noticed right now that these elements are not on the source page, I get the html from the inspector. So its possible that there are added dynamically (but there are on the screen when i run the jquery code)

Comment: If the elements you're targeting are dynamically loaded then that's the most likely problem. You need to run your `for` loop *after* they have loaded.

Comment: @Eddie I don't know if it changes anything but check my previous comment

Comment: Add this line inside the `for` loop: `console.log($('#' + response.listOfObjects[i].id).length)` - if it's zero (0) then the elements don't exist at that time.

Comment: @freedomn-m there is '1' for every object from the list

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I checked what freedomn-m mentioned and it looks like these elements exists

Comment: Hmm. Are there any plugins used for the inputs?

Answer (score 0):

Based on author's code, I assume, that the expected output is `[{id:singleValue}]`. In this case I suggest you to use [Array.reduce()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reduce.asp) method which perfectly does work for you. I've tried to add few comments in the code:

```js
const response = { // sample response for testing purpose
  listOfObjects: [{
      id: 'id1',
      singleValue: 1
    },
    {
      id: 'id2',
      singleValue: 2
    },
    {
      id: 'id3',
      singleValue: 3
    },
  ]
}

const mapped = response.listOfObjects.reduce(function(accumulator, currValue) {
  // here goes simple object transformation
  let obj = {};
  obj[currValue.id] = currValue.singleValue;
  accumulator.push(obj);

  return accumulator; // each iteration should retrun accumulator
}, []); // here you define starting object for your reduce method

console.log(mapped);
```

Comment: The use of `reduce()` here isn't really warranted, and is not what the OP is asking for.